# How to migrate terser webpack plugin to webpack v5

Tags: webpack-5

> If you are using webpack v5 or above you do not need to install this plugin. Webpack v5 comes with the latest terser-webpack-plugin out of the box.

I am going to use webpack v5, so per doc, I removed terser: `npm uninstall terser-webpack-plugin`. But I am not sure how to migrate the following settings which were set for webpack v4 + TerserPlugin:

```
optimization: {
    minimizer: [
      new TerserPlugin({
        sourceMap: true,
        terserOptions: {
          output: {
            comments: /^!/,
          },
        },
        extractComments: false,
      }),
    ],
  },
```

I Could not find the document online. Can anyone help, please?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the following TerserPlugin config and it works well with webpack v5!

```js
  optimization: {
    minimize: true,
    minimizer: [
      new TerserPlugin({
        test: /\.js(\?.*)?$/i, // you should add this property
        extractComments: false,
        terserOptions: {
          compress: {
            drop_console: true,
            drop_debugger: true,
            pure_funcs: ['console.log', 'console.info'], // Delete console
          },
        },
      }),
    ],
  },
```

Comment: what about `cache, parallel, sourceMap` options ?